# scala/java : icon for button with a relative path

Tags: java, swing, scala, button, imageicon

It is a classic question but even with a stack overflow search I did not found an answer.
The problem concerns the retrieval of an image with a relative path.

With an absolute path it works, and [here](http://i39.tinypic.com/28k5wsj.jpg) you can see the code using the statement getClass.getResource(filename), with the directory structure of my project.
It's the same I think in Java.

Maven structure:

```
src
 - main
   - java
     - lanceur.scala
   - resources
     - down_arrow.png
```

Code:

```
btn_bas.icon= new ImagaeIcon(Fenetre.getClass()
                    .getResource("../resources/down_arrow.png"))
```

Comment: What is your question? Can you outline how your package and directory structure looks like? Add a code example?

Comment: Please do not use screenshots for code - this is very lazy.

Comment: Try `"/resources/down_arrow.png"`.  The leading `/` conveys, 'ignore packages and search from the root of the class-path'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your classpath is both the *java* and *resources* directory. In a JAR there is nothing below them.

Try `"/down_arrow.png"`.

Comment: ok, it works! Note that besides this syntax, there were an other issue: I use netbeans in which _projects_ are divided in _modules_; and in my project I had two modules each with a "Fenetre" class; so retrieving the path of Fenetre lead to the wrong one.